# Unpack list of lists into list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of lists of tuples:

```
a = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7, 8), (9, 10)]]
```

How can I make one list of tuples:

```
b = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Naive way is:

```
b = []
for c in a:
    for t in c:
        b.append(t)
```

List comprehension or any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: `[i for b in a for i in b]`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 this is open question, i am interested in different approaches :)

Comment: The best way IMO is using reduce from the functools module. `b = functools.reduce(list.__add__, a)`

Comment: @Nick no it doesn't, it takes only the first element

Comment: @JackHoman how is that "the best way"? It is a quadratic time algorithm when you can do it in linear time easily.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I said in my opinion. "Best" is probably the wrong way to describe it. It seems to be the most clear way to do it. What is the linear way to do it?

Comment: `[x for sub in a for x in sub]` or an equivalent for-loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga am I missing something? Theres two for loops in that list comprehension.... that's also quadratic running time. I just timed it and reduce is faster. Not trying to be argumentative. If I'm not understanding something, then I'd like to learn

Comment: @JackHoman just because there are two for-loops doesn't make it quadratic time. Where `n` is the number of elements in all the sublists, then that is O(N) time, it only touches each element once. Using `+` you get a *new list each time* each intermediate step, touching all the elments you already touched again and again...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh okay, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @JackHoman just for good measure, here's some empirical evidence: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/0ed8e599cbc8a8605abbe919df84c5fa

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's really interesting. When I timed it, reduce seemed to be faster every time. I guess I should probably do it at a larger scale before making assumptions

Answer (score 11):

Using **itertools**

**demo:**

```
import itertools
a = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7, 8), (9, 10)]]
print(list(itertools.chain(*a)))
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: Let `chain.from_iterable` do the unpacking rather than using `*`.

Comment: Use 'reduce' if you want to use a in-built python function : in your case that would be  ' b = reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, a) '

Answer (score 8):

This operation is called 'flatten' in some of other languages.
In python, followings method might be shortest.

```
a = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7, 8), (9, 10)]]
sum(a, [])
// [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

It also work in the case the parent list have many child lists.

```
b = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
sum(b, [])
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Do not use `sum` to flatten a list, it is quadratic time

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to append, you want to extend. You can use the really simple loop

```
a = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], [(7, 8), (9, 10)]]
single_level_list = []
for lst in a:
    single_level_list.extend(lst)

print(single_level_list)

>>> [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: `for lst in a:    single_level_list += lst` is the same better readable